# C++ fstream.write segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sqlite, fstream, binary-data

I am trying to write binary data to file and I get segmentation fault. I get binary data from sqlite blob.
i need some help with this code.
Error blow up on write command. 
sqlite callback:

```
    static int callback(void* object, int, char** data, char**)
{
    if (fromdb* const art= static_cast<fromdb*>(object))
    {
        art->title = *data[1];
        art->creator = *data[2];
        art->bin = data[3];
        art->year = *data[4];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Write function:

```
    void write() {
    // << bin;
    ofstream towrite;
    string name;
    cout << "Podaj nazwe pliku do zapisu";
    cin >> name;
    towrite.open(name, ios::out | ios::binary);
    towrite.write(bin, sizeof(bin));
    towrite.close();
}
```

Comment: You have lots of pointers - what are they pointing to? A common reason for a segmentation fault is that they are not pointing anywhere (uninitialized)

Comment: I was trying to understand your callback function's input, could not understand anything to be hones.

Comment: try art->bin = *data[3]; ?

Comment: When is the callback called? When does the segfault happen? In your `write` function? Does that ask for the `name` variable or blow up before then? There's not enough info in the question to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_exec()` is just a wrapper around a preapre/step/finalize loop.

The [sqlite3_exec() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) says:

> The 3rd argument to the sqlite3_exec() callback is an array of pointers to strings obtained as if from [sqlite3_column_text()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), one for each column.

That documentation says:

> These routines may only be called when the most recent call to [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) has returned [SQLITE_ROW](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#row) and neither [sqlite3_reset()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) nor [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) have been called subsequently. If any of these routines are called after [sqlite3_reset()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) or [sqlite3_finalize()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) or after [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) has returned something other than [SQLITE_ROW](http://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#row), the results are undefined.

In other words: the strings go away after the callback returns; you must copy the contents of the strings.